# rmagick - undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rmagick

I just clone existing project trying setup that project getting rmagick issue.. How resolve this issue "undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads". I am using ubuntu 10.04

```
rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads - /home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:67:in `rescue in block in <module:RMagick>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/carrierwave-0.8.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:64:in `block in <module:RMagick>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/concern.rb:119:in `class_eval'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/concern.rb:119:in `append_features'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:6:in `include'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:6:in `<class:ImageUploader>'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/models/picture.rb:21:in `<class:Picture>'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/models/picture.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/models/coach.rb:10:in `<class:Coach>'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/models/coach.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/app/admin/coaches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:190:in `block in load!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:190:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:190:in `load!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:213:in `routes'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/config/routes.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeadmin-0.5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__559059627__prepare__612694797__callbacks'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/prasanna/Projects/sportybird-webapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Did you install Rmagick and how did you install this?

Comment: Yes I installed Rmagick, but getting following error           require 'RMagick' ==> LoadError: /home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads - /home/prasanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install it with brew or other command?
I advise you to remove rmagick, install brew then install with brew the rmagick and imagemagick.